# При запуске оконного приложения C++ в Visual Studio 2019 ничего не происходит

Tags: c++-cli, ui

Пробовал изменить подсистему на консоль, ничего не изменилось, при запуске ничего не происходит.

```
#pragma once
#include "math.h"

namespace Project5 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Сводка для MyForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: добавьте код конструктора
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Освободить все используемые ресурсы.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button1;
    protected:
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox^ comboBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label4;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox4;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox^ checkBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label5;

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Обязательная переменная конструктора.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Требуемый метод для поддержки конструктора — не изменяйте 
        /// содержимое этого метода с помощью редактора кода.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->comboBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox());
            this->label4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->checkBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox());
            this->label5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(219, 277);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(109, 25);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->button1->Text = L"Решить";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button1_Click);
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->AutoSize = true;
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(42, 25);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(25, 17);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 1;
            this->label1->Text = L"X=";
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this->label2->AutoSize = true;
            this->label2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(42, 75);
            this->label2->Name = L"label2";
            this->label2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(25, 17);
            this->label2->TabIndex = 2;
            this->label2->Text = L"A=";
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this->label3->AutoSize = true;
            this->label3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(42, 126);
            this->label3->Name = L"label3";
            this->label3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(25, 17);
            this->label3->TabIndex = 3;
            this->label3->Text = L"C=";
            // 
            // comboBox1
            // 
            this->comboBox1->FormattingEnabled = true;
            this->comboBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(381, 22);
            this->comboBox1->Name = L"comboBox1";
            this->comboBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(121, 24);
            this->comboBox1->TabIndex = 4;
            // 
            // label4
            // 
            this->label4->AutoSize = true;
            this->label4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(282, 22);
            this->label4->Name = L"label4";
            this->label4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(67, 17);
            this->label4->TabIndex = 5;
            this->label4->Text = L"Функция";
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(73, 22);
            this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
            this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 22);
            this->textBox1->TabIndex = 6;
            // 
            // textBox2
            // 
            this->textBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(73, 72);
            this->textBox2->Name = L"textBox2";
            this->textBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 22);
            this->textBox2->TabIndex = 7;
            // 
            // textBox3
            // 
            this->textBox3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(73, 123);
            this->textBox3->Name = L"textBox3";
            this->textBox3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 22);
            this->textBox3->TabIndex = 8;
            // 
            // textBox4
            // 
            this->textBox4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(36, 167);
            this->textBox4->Multiline = true;
            this->textBox4->Name = L"textBox4";
            this->textBox4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(476, 100);
            this->textBox4->TabIndex = 9;
            // 
            // checkBox1
            // 
            this->checkBox1->AutoSize = true;
            this->checkBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(381, 96);
            this->checkBox1->Name = L"checkBox1";
            this->checkBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(18, 17);
            this->checkBox1->TabIndex = 10;
            this->checkBox1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // label5
            // 
            this->label5->AutoSize = true;
            this->label5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(282, 95);
            this->label5->Name = L"label5";
            this->label5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(33, 17);
            this->label5->TabIndex = 11;
            this->label5->Text = L"Max";

            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(8, 16);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(542, 314);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label5);
            this->Controls->Add(this->checkBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox4);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label4);
            this->Controls->Add(this->comboBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"MyForm";
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::MyForm_Load);
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion
        int main()
        {
            return 0;
        };
    private: System::Void MyForm_Load(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        comboBox1->Items->Add("Косинус");
        comboBox1->Items->Add("Синус");
        comboBox1->Items->Add("Тангенс");
        textBox1->Clear();
        textBox2->Clear();
        textBox3->Clear();
        textBox4->Clear();
    }
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    Double X, A, C, res, MA, y = 0;
    X = Convert::ToDouble(textBox1->Text);
    A = Convert::ToDouble(textBox2->Text);
    C = Convert::ToDouble(textBox3->Text);
    switch (comboBox1->SelectedIndex)
    {
    case 0: res = cos(X); textBox4->Text = String::Format("cos(x) равен {0:F4}", res); break;
    case 1: res = sin(X); textBox4->Text = String::Format("sin(x) равен {0:F4}", res); break;
    case 2: res = tan(X); textBox4->Text = String::Format("tan(x) равен {0:F4}", res); break;
    }
    y = pow(sin(res), 2) + A * pow(cos(pow(X, 3)), 5) + C * log(pow(X, 0.4));
    textBox4->Text += String::Format("\r\ny = {0:F4}", y) + String::Format("\n при res = {0:F4}", res);
    if (X > A) MA = X;
    else MA = A;
    if (C > MA) MA = C;
    if (checkBox1->Checked) {
        textBox4->Text = textBox4->Text + Environment::NewLine + String::Format("Max равен {0:F4}", MA);
    }
}
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Удалите из кода метод `main`.

Если вы создавали проект с помощью готового шаблона, то у вас должен быть файл Program.h со следующим содержимым:

```
#pragma once
#include "MyForm.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

ref class Program
{
public:
    Program();

    [STAThreadAttribute]
    static void Main() {
        Application::EnableVisualStyles();
        Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Application::Run(gcnew Project5::MyForm());
    }
};
```

Если его нет - создайте.